# ctx.body undefined in async/await function

Tags: node.js, api, server, async-await, koa

I'm trying to return from my node server with koa to my angular front end the result of an api call. Here's my controller which require a npm module which provides access to their api. Await should wait for the result and than return, am I wrong? I did something similar in a previous project but I was asking data from a db.
Why it is not working?

```
const color = require('colourlovers');

exports.getAllColors = async (ctx) => {
  ctx.res.body = await color.get('/color/FFFFFF', { format: 'json' }, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);//<---here is logging the data
    return data;
  });
  console.log(ctx.res.body);//<---here is undefined
  ctx.status=200;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not await `color.get` because it uses callbacks instead of promises (well, you *can* await it, but it doesn't do what you'd expect). So to use await, you need to build the promise yourself:

```
ctx.res.body = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    color.get('/color/FFFFFF', { format: 'json' }, (err, data) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        else resolve(data);
    });
});
```

Now it'll wait for the promise to be resolved or rejected.